# Date Object in Javascript works problematic for 22 March in IRST Timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

I'm working with firefox 14.0.1. I had a problem in my web application date conversion. Tracing the bug I noticed that it seems javascript Date object has some bugs. Here is a printscreen of firebug watch in that tow different dates result in a same date. My question is that is this a firefox javascript engine bug or I missed something

[printscreen of firebug http://upload.tehran98.com/upme/uploads/7ae77453a8e9448f1.png](http://upload.tehran98.com/upme/uploads/7ae77453a8e9448f1.png)

Comment: You did test before and after the DST change and you managed to get a screen shot. Please tell, you **wanted** to get that and ask a tricky question, didn't you ?

Comment: @dystroy this issue presents itself whether you're in DST or not; try it yourself with the date for DST in your own locality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's gonna be due to daylight savings time, which is between midnight March 21 and midnight March 22 [in Tehran](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2014.html).

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2014,2,21))
```

Date.UTC will give you [a timestamp based on the UTC timezone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC), which won't be affected by DST.

When you do `new Date(2014, 2, 21);` you get a Date object that represents midnight on that date, which is then translated into the current time settings, which includes the extra hour for Daylight Savings Time.